# How to efficiently create (read-only) both a snapshot and a diffshot at the same time?

Tags: rsync, snapshot

I use `rsync` to regularly create snapshots of some directories via

```
PAR="-aP --chmod=a-w --no-owner"
# Create diffshot
rsync $PAR --compare-dest=$CURRENT_SNAPSHOT $SOURCE/ $DEST.changeset.incomplete
find $DEST.changeset.incomplete -type d -empty -delete
mv $DEST.changeset{.incomplete,}
# Create actual snapshot
LNK="--link-dest=$PREVIOUS --link-dest=$DEST.changeset"
rsync $PAR $LNK $SOURCE/ $DEST.incomplete
mv $DEST{.incomplete,}
```

such that `$DEST` contains a snapshot (hard-linking to the previous snapshot at `$PREVIOUS`) and `$DEST.changeset` contains a rudimentary diffshot, i.e. only the files which have been modified or created (but no information on simple `mv`s or file removal). To make the snapshots read-only I simply have `rsync` use `--chmod=a-w` - the original permissions are not that important, since it's basically always `ug+w`, but I wonder if there are other, more efficient means to achieve read-only status. Anyway, my main question is

> How can the two calls `rsync` be combined into one / sped up?